# How to differentiate test description for parameterized data testing with selenium/cucumber?

Tags: selenium, cucumber

How to differentiate test description for parameterized data testing with cucumber? Because for multiple testdata, the description in the scenario outline is showing same when viewing the cucumber report.

 Below I am giving an example. On cucumber result, the scenario outline "Verify correct status displaying after filtering" -always visible as same for all the testdata. Is it possible to show three different description for three different testdata? Like "Verify correct verified status displaying after filtering" / "Verify correct pending status displaying after filtering" / "Verify correct rejected status displaying after filtering".

```
@flights
@flight01
Scenario Outline: TC003_Verify correct status displaying after filtering
    
    Given I am in the xyz application   
    When I navigate to abcd page
    Then Select status "<Status>" from the filter
    Then Verify correct "<Status>" should be displayed
    
    
Examples:
|Status  |
|Verified|
|Pending |
|Rejected|
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the scenario outline?

Comment: I have updated the scenario outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do that would be to add the parameter to your scenario outline the same way you do for your steps:
eg.

```
TC003_Verify "<Status>" status displaying after filtering for "<Status>"
```

This way your scenario results will better convey what you are testing too.
HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to just write 3 different scenarios with different titles. There is absolutely no need to use scenario outline when cuking.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested for multiple test data,cucumber report shows the data itself and marked it with pass or fail colors, screenshots  below . The description in scenario outline is same but it also copies all the data and it even provides the error. Imo, this eliminates the need to have separate scenario outline with data in it.

[image]

and

[image]

You have not mention which test runner are you using but the above screen shots are from  `cucumber 6.9.1` and `Junit5` and in `junit-platform.properties` , you can mention `cucumber.plugin = html:target/cucumber.html` to have this report generated